# Postgres server uses all of RAM and SWAP

Tags: postgresql, memory, ubuntu

The Postgres Server Uses all of 120GB RAM and all SWAP! Is there anything wrong? How can I fix this?

This is postgres config

```
shared_buffers = 30GB
work_mem = 24MB              # It's limited for the main user to 6MB
maintenance_work_mem = 10GB
effective_cache_size = 60GB
max_connections = 2048       # It's limited by pgBouncer pools to 600 connections
```

And Ubuntu RAM usage:

```
# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          123Gi        36Gi       531Mi        30Gi        86Gi        55Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi       4.0Gi          0B
```

And this is `htop`  output:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you are worrying needlessly. `free` shows that there are 55GB available. It is entirely normal to have very little unused memory, since the kernel uses all otherwise unused memory to cache files.

It is also no problem if your swap is used, as long as you don't have to read pages from the swap space regularly. Perhaps you can tune the kernel to `vm.swappiness = 1` so that it doesn't swap out memory needlessly.